# 'NoneType object has no attribute ' send'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

My code is returning this error `NoneType object has no attribute 'send'`

here is my code

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

class Logging(commands.Cog):
    """Sets up logging for you guild"""
    
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.bot = client

    async def __error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send(error)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message,):

         deleted = embed = discord.Embed(
             description=f"Message deleted in {message.channel.mention}", color=0x4040EC
         ).set_author(name=message.author, url= discord.Embed.Empty, icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)

         
         
         
         channel = client.get_channel(888600482317213786)
         deleted.add_field(name="Message", value=message.content)
         deleted.timestamp = message.created_at
         await channel.send(embed=deleted)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Logging(client))
```

I am doing this in my cogs and not in the main.py

Comment: I would recommend you to use something like a config.py file to store the server variables like channel ID or role ID and refer to them by variable name. That way, you'll have significantly less headache down the road to figure out which IDs are those.

Comment: Please include all code inside code blocks. And fix indentation since meaning can change with different indentations. It might ask you to add description but a few lines will do it. Dont use spam but add a description of what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

`channel = client.get_channel(888600482317213786)` should be `channel = self.bot.get_channel(888600482317213786)`. Then check if channel is None.
I assume there is no indentation error in your actual code.